# Is it possible for a webserver(Apache) to acces/read a file from a diffrent local network segment?

Tags: php, apache, settings, local, network-share

Im trying to read a file inside a shared folder within my local network. Opening the file and navigating towards the file in both the windows explorer and the browser works perfectly fine. However im trying to read the file inside a PHP file and i cant seem to get it to work. After some troubleshooting I think the problem is that the shared folder is inside a diffrent ip segment then my apache server(if it got one when installed on the computer).

Im doing a `file_exists()` to check if the file is there and i can reach it, but i cant seem to acces the file or the filepath within PHP. The path is formatted as `\\computer\share\file` as it should be with a network location. The problem(as far as i know) is that the server runs on `192.168.10.x` and the file im trying to acces is on `192.168.1.x`

I have to questions about this,

1. Is it possible for Apache acces to multiple local networks like `192.168.1.x` aswell as `192.168.10.x`?
2. If this is possible do i have to change any setting or policies within Apache or my shared drive?

I hope I informed you enough about my problem, if anything isnt clear feel free to ask and ill be happy to inform you with any information required.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, research ALIAS, add one to your Virtual Host

Comment: @RiggsFolly would this work if my server runs on `192.168.10.50` and my file is on `192.168.1.50`? and does it get the file on startup or keeps reading the file?